# Does the intersection of 2 closed sets not include the end points?

Tags: real-analysis

I am new to Set Theory and when learning in the book, I came across this question which answer I don't understand.

$\bigcap\limits_{i \in {\mathrm{I}\!\mathbb{N}}} [i,i+1]=\varnothing$

Since  $[1,2]\cap [2,3]=\left\{2\right\}$, wouldn't $\bigcap\limits_{i \in {\mathrm{I}\!\mathrm{N}}} [i,i+1]=\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the intersection has to be in all the sets.  Just taking three terms we have $$[1,2]\cap[2,3] \cap [3,4]=\{2\}\cap [3,4]=\emptyset$$
and the intersection of the empty set with anything is empty.